# Spring Server Invoke Only One FilterRegistrationBean

Tags: java, spring, filter

I'm trying to make a filter system for checking if the token is valid.

Using FilterRegistrationBean to make three different path to three different client type controllers, and when I'm making requests from the different controllers on the swagger UI, only the first filter invoke

here only the company FilterRegistrationBean will be invoke
if I will do a request to admin or customer URL the filter will not invoke

this is the FilterRegistrationBean Component

```
@Component
public class CompanyFilterComponent {

@Bean(name = "companyFilter")
public FilterRegistrationBean<ClientFilter> companyFilter(JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
    System.out.println("company");
    FilterRegistrationBean<ClientFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new ClientFilter(jwtUtil,ClientType.Company));
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(0);
    filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/company/*");
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}


@Bean(name = "adminFilter")
public FilterRegistrationBean<ClientFilter> adminFilter(JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
    System.out.println("admin");
    FilterRegistrationBean<ClientFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new ClientFilter(jwtUtil, ClientType.Administrator));
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(1);
    filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/admin/*");
    
    return filterRegistrationBean;

}
@Bean(name = "customerFilter")
public FilterRegistrationBean<ClientFilter> customerFilter(JwtUtil jwtUtil) {
    System.out.println("customer");
    FilterRegistrationBean<ClientFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new ClientFilter(jwtUtil,ClientType.Customer));
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(2);
    filterRegistrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/customer/*");
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
}
```

this is the filter for all the three FilterRegistrationBean

```
public class ClientFilter implements Filter {

private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
private ClientType client;

public ClientFilter(JwtUtil jwtUtil, ClientType client) {
    this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    final String token = request.getHeader("token");
    System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
    System.out.println(jwtUtil.extractClientType(token)+"   ---  "+this.client);
    try {
        if (token != null) {
            if (jwtUtil.extractClientType(token).equals(this.client)) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {
                // if not logged in - block the request
                response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "you are not logged in");
            }
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), "no token received");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), e.getMessage());

    }
}
}
```

and an example of a REAST controller function in one of the controllers

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/company")
@CrossOrigin
public class CompanyController {

@Autowired
private CompanyService companyService;
@Autowired
private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
@PostMapping("/coupon")
public Coupon addCoupon(@RequestBody Coupon coupon, @RequestHeader String token) {

    try {
        int id=jwtUtil.extractId(token);
        return this.companyService.addCoupon(coupon,id);
    } catch (CouponSystemException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
    }
}

@PutMapping("/coupon")
public Coupon updateCoupon(@RequestBody Coupon coupon, @RequestHeader String token) {
    
    try {
        int id=jwtUtil.extractId(token);
        return this.companyService.updateCoupon(coupon,id);
    } catch (CouponSystemException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

thanks for the help!

*** forget to the I have anther FilterRegistrationBean for the cross origin
but with another filter
code:

```
@Component
public class AppCorsConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new         
UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedOriginPattern("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new         
FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to change the bean.setOrder(1) in AppCorsConfiguration and try if the admin filter is called or not

Comment: the same resault

Answer (score 0):

change your setOrder to 0 for all and try

Comment: still, only the company filter works